# Upload picture to Digital Ocean Space using Expo

Tags: javascript, expo, digital-ocean

I'm trying to upload the image result from the `takePictureAsync` function to a Digital Ocean Space using Expo. Currently the upload process using signed PUT URL seems to work fine, but something is going wrong during the encoding process. Below I've included the relevant code:

```
const pictureResponse = await camera.current.takePictureAsync({ base64: true });

const spacesBase64 = `data:image/png;base64,${pictureResponse.base64}`;
const spacesBuffer = Buffer.from(spacesBase64, "base64");
const spacesBlob = new Blob([spacesBuffer]);
const spacesFile = new File([spacesBlob], "test.jpg", { type: "image/jpeg" });

fetch(`https://signedputurl.com`, { method: 'PUT', body: spacesFile });
```

When I take a picture it shows up on my Digital Ocean Space just fine. The file size also seems correct. When I try to preview the URL it doesn't render. I've tried removing the `data:image/png;base64` prefix, but this doesn't fix the problem.

I've made the image result public and it can be viewed at https://disposable-dev.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/with_base64_prefix.jpg, I figured it might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out a solution! Instead of parsing the base64 results back into a blob. I can just use a `fetch` request to get the blob from cache.

```
const pictureResponse = await camera.current.takePictureAsync();

const spacesRespond = await fetch(pictureResponse.uri);
const spacesBlob = await spacesRespond.blob();

fetch(`https://signedputurl.com`, { method: 'PUT', body: spacesBlob });
```